Hu moments for letter detection and classification
I am trying to use Hu moments to detect the letters 'H', 'S', and 'U' in Open MV. They always have the same size and typography, stuck on a white background, but no matter how many corrections I make, it doesn't work well. Is there anything I can do to improve the detection, or should I give up and opt for using a TensorFlow model?
import sensor, image, time, math
from pyb import UART
import rv.moments
import vec.distance
from machine import LED

# Configuración inicial
sensor.reset()
sensor.set_pixformat(sensor.GRAYSCALE)
sensor.set_framesize(sensor.QVGA)
sensor.skip_frames(time=2000)
sensor.set_auto_whitebal(False)
clock = time.clock()

uart = UART(3, 115200, timeout_char=1000)

time.sleep_ms(500)


UMBRAL_BINARIZACION = (100, 255)
MIN_BLOB_AREA = 700
MAX_BLOB_AREA = 8000
MARGEN = 3
VOTACION_FRAMES = 3
UMBRAL_CUADROS_NO_VALIDOS = 15
cuadros_no_validos = 0
historial_detecciones = []


MOMENTOS_RELEVANTES = [4, 5, 1]
UMBRAL_SIMILITUD_INICIAL = 10
UMBRAL_SIMILITUD = UMBRAL_SIMILITUD_INICIAL
UMBRAL_SIMILITUD_MINIMO = 5

referencia_H = [3.221695, -0.282843,  0.284073]
referencia_S = [-10.5604, -7.18191, 2.54211]
referencia_U = [-18.37175443, 12.77949927, 7.10455959]


def preprocesar_imagen(img):
    img.median(1, percentile=0.7)
    img_bin = img.binary([UMBRAL_BINARIZACION], invert=True)
    img_bin.close(1)
    img_bin.open(1)
    return img_bin

# Detectar el blob más grande y centrado
# Función para encontrar el blob más grande y centrado
def detectar_blob_centrado(img):
    blobs = img.find_blobs([(1, 255)], pixels_threshold=10, area_threshold=10)
    if blobs:
        blob_centrado = min(
            [blob for blob in blobs if MIN_BLOB_AREA <= blob.area() <= MAX_BLOB_AREA],

            key=lambda b: abs(b.cx() - img.width()//2) + abs(b.cy() - img.height()//2),
            default=None
        )
        return blob_centrado
    return None


def recortar_blob(img, blob):
    if blob:
        x, y, w, h = blob.rect()
        x = max(0, x - MARGEN)
        y = max(0, y - MARGEN)
        w = min(img.width() - x, w + 2 * MARGEN)
        h = min(img.height() - y, h + 2 * MARGEN)
        roi_img = img.copy(roi=(x, y, w, h))
        img.draw_rectangle(x, y, w, h, color=(255, 0, 0))
        return roi_img
    return img

# Normalización
def normalizar_rotacion(img, roi):
    x, y, w, h = roi
    roi_img = img.copy(roi=roi)
    blobs = roi_img.find_blobs([(1, 255)], pixels_threshold=MIN_BLOB_AREA, area_threshold=MIN_BLOB_AREA, merge=True)
    if not blobs:
        return roi_img
    blob = blobs[0]
    if blob.major_axis_line():
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = blob.major_axis_line()
        angulo = math.degrees(math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1))
        return roi_img.rotation_corr(z_rotation=angulo)
    return roi_img

# Extracción de características
def extraer_caracteristicas(img):
    momentos_hu = rv.moments.hu(img)
    caracteristicas = [momentos_hu[i] for i in MOMENTOS_RELEVANTES]

    # Imprimir los momentos de Hu detectados
    print(f"Momentos de Hu detectados: {momentos_hu}")

    return caracteristicas



def clasificar_letra(caracteristicas):
    distancia_H = vec.distance.euclidean(caracteristicas, referencia_H)
    distancia_S = vec.distance.euclidean(caracteristicas, referencia_S)
    distancia_U = vec.distance.euclidean(caracteristicas, referencia_U)

    min_distancia = min(distancia_H, distancia_S, distancia_U)

    if min_distancia > UMBRAL_SIMILITUD:
        return None
    if min_distancia == distancia_H:
        return 'H'
    elif min_distancia == distancia_S:
        return 'S'
    elif min_distancia == distancia_U:
        return 'U'


def ajustar_umbral_similitud():
    global UMBRAL_SIMILITUD
    if cuadros_no_validos >= UMBRAL_CUADROS_NO_VALIDOS and UMBRAL_SIMILITUD > UMBRAL_SIMILITUD_MINIMO:
        UMBRAL_SIMILITUD -= 1
        print(f"Reduciendo umbral de similitud a {UMBRAL_SIMILITUD}")


def actualizar_historial(letra_detectada):
    global historial_detecciones, cuadros_no_validos

    if letra_detectada:
        cuadros_no_validos = 0
        historial_detecciones.append(letra_detectada)
        if len(historial_detecciones) > VOTACION_FRAMES:
            historial_detecciones.pop(0)
    else:
        cuadros_no_validos += 1
        ajustar_umbral_similitud()
        if cuadros_no_validos >= UMBRAL_CUADROS_NO_VALIDOS:
            historial_detecciones.clear()
            cuadros_no_validos = 0

def determinar_letra_final():
    if len(historial_detecciones) == VOTACION_FRAMES:
        letra_mas_frecuente = max(set(historial_detecciones), key=historial_detecciones.count)
        return letra_mas_frecuente
    return None


def procesar_imagen():
    img = sensor.snapshot()
    img_bin = preprocesar_imagen(img)
    blob = detectar_blob_centrado(img_bin)
    if blob:
        roi_img = recortar_blob(img_bin, blob)
        img_rotada = normalizar_rotacion(img_bin, blob.rect())
        caracteristicas = extraer_caracteristicas(img_rotada)
        letra_detectada = clasificar_letra(caracteristicas)
        actualizar_historial(letra_detectada)
        letra_final = determinar_letra_final()

        if letra_final:
            x, y, w, h = blob.rect()
            img.draw_string(x, y - 10, letra_final, color=(255, 0, 0), scale=2)
            uart.write(f"Letra detectada: {letra_final}")
            print(f"Letra detectada: {letra_final}")
        else:
            print("No se detectó una letra válida")


while True:

    procesar_imagen()
    time.sleep(0.1)


I have tried adjusting the binarization threshold, modifying morphology values, and considering all 7 Hu moments instead of just the 3 main ones. I've also set additional thresholds to filter out errors. Even so, the detection still isn’t working correctly.
